# Change np.seterr behavior inside a function only

Tags: python, numpy

I want to change the floating point error handling of numpy inside of a single function.

Typical example:

```
import numpy as np

def f():
    np.seterr(all='raise')
    # Do some other stuff

print(np.seterr())
# {'divide': 'warn', 'over': 'warn', 'under': 'ignore', 'invalid': 'warn'}

f()
print(np.seterr())
# {'divide': 'raise', 'over': 'raise', 'under': 'raise', 'invalid': 'raise'}
```

I would like the call to `f`to not change the output of  `np.seterr()`, I have no idea how to do this.

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`numpy.errstate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.errstate.html) context manager to change floating-point error handling temporarily:

```
def f():
    with numpy.errstate(all='raise'):
        ...
```

Be aware that while this is a temporary change, it is still global across threads and coroutines. As of the time of this writing, NumPy doesn't offer an option for thread-local or [`contextvars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html)-based error settings.

As of NumPy 1.17, it is also possible to use `numpy.errstate` as a function decorator, with the same effect as wrapping the whole body in a `with numpy.errstate(...):` block:

```
@numpy.errstate(all='raise')
def f():
    ...
```

Comment: Woah that's neat. I didn't know about that!

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was after :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can achieve this by resetting how errors are handled at the end of your function, i.e.:

```
def f():
    err = np.geterr()
    np.seterr(all='raise')
    try:
        # do stuff
    finally:
        np.seterr(**err)
```